# Updating the delta value on a custom field

Tags: 7, database

I have a content type with an image field and I am trying to update the delta value. I'm assuming the delta value is used to sort the images when they're rendered. (If there is a better way please tell)

I'm not sure if this is the Drupal way of doing it but cannot find any resources on how to do this correctly.

I have a page that allows the user to change the order of the images through the jquery-ui sortable method, this then posts to an admin page where I intend to do the database updates.

Firstly, is this the correct way to update the delta value on a field?

I know direct queries on the db aren't a good idea at all.

If it is, I cannot actually change the value initially as the database delta column is unique, it's also doesn't allow for a null value so I'm stumped on how to achieve this, without running two queries. One to set/clear current values, then one to update with proper values.

Any ideas welcome. I'm using D7.

Comment: Yes, the Delta controls the order of values in a multi-value field. You can use the JS draggable table, or without JS you get a form to choose the weight number to tell Drupal in which order to save the values. Smaller numbers float up to head the list, larger numbers drop down to the of end of the list. The Delta/weight numbers for the particular order are then saved from 0 onwards. Why do you need to change the order after the user has already done so?

Comment: The user is not happy with using the Drupal form draggable / weight system.  There are quite a few images in each portfolio and they want a simple page to drag and drop the actual images to the order they want.

Comment: I have got it working but the need to flush the cache to 'update' the final sort order is not performant at all. I'm going to take a look at field_attach_update

Comment: You don't need to flush the cache, you just need to invalidate it for the single node that's been updated. `entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($node->nid));` will do it